# Pointcut Expression for specific methods in different packages

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I tried pointcut expression for a specific package like `com.abc.def.controller`, `com.abc.def.service.serviceImpl`, etc in `@Around` advice as:

```
@Around("execution(* com.abc.def.controller..*.*(..))")
@Around("execution(* com.abc.def.service.*Impl.*(..))")
```

I also need to match methods in different packages like `com.abc.xyz.controller`, `com.abc.xyz.service.serviceImpl` and tried many pointcut expressions but didn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```java
@Around("execution(* com.abc..controller..*(..))")
@Around("execution(* com.abc..service.*Impl.*(..))")
```

You can also match both at once like this:

```java
@Around(
    "execution(* com.abc..controller..*(..)) || " + 
    "execution(* com.abc..service.*Impl.*(..))"
)
```

Other variants are possible, depending on what exactly you want to achieve. Feel free to ask related follow-up questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question that, I just added some more statement in the controller expression as, @Around("execution(* com.abc..controller..*(..)) && @annotation(CustomAnnotation)"). It doesn't worked. Did I miss some any code or any confioguration needed for this ?

Comment: In AspectJ annotation-based syntax you need to use a fully qualified class name like `com.abc.blah.CustomAnnotation`. In native AspectJ syntax this would not be necessary.

Comment: Here's my annotation interface...                                                                                                                        import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
 String methodName();
 String type();
}

Comment: any other configuration needed ?

Comment: Package name!!! Please use the fully qualified class name including package name in your pointcut like in my example from the previous comment. Again: `@Around("execution(* com.abc..controller..*(..)) && @annotation(my.package.name.MyAnnotation)")`

Answer (score 0):

Try below expression for the same,

> @Around("execution(* com.abc.def.controller.*.*(..))")

Comment: It only matches methods from the package com.abc.def. I need both com.abc.def and com.abc.xyz. I'm trying to generalize it.

Comment: I didn't tried, but you may  @Around("within(com.abc..*)")